# startActivity is not starting my Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have an Activity name "IntroActivity" that is the "Launcher" activity for the app and after some decision making opens up a new Activity named "HomeActivity".

In my HomeActivity I have an ActionBar with a "Log Out" Action (which is in the menu but set to appear as an Action) which is supposed to do some operations and return the user to the "IntroActivity".

However, the startActivity method used inside HomeActivity does not work and there are no errors generated. I have debugged the code and the onOptionsItemSelected method is definitely executed as is the correct case inside. Here is the code:

HomeActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {        
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_standard, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_standard_settings:{
            // TODO
            return true;
        }

        case R.id.menu_standard_logout:{
            //Set logged in to false and then return the user to the intro page
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("logged_in", false);
            Intent introIntent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);             
            startActivity(introIntent);

            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The Manifest includes:

```
 <activity
       android:name="com.kennel39.diabeteslive_adtdev.IntroActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>            
 </activity>
```

I'm not sure what else I can provide that will be of use but I will quickly post up any extra parts if required. 
Thanks in advance,
Josh

Comment: your code inside side IntroActivity is Finishing this, debug you code and checks the conditions properly you will get out of this.

Comment: I think the answers from Prakash M and Thomas Bouron are probably right. I'd guess the `IntroActivity` is in fact being started but because you failed to `commit()` the "logged_in" preference, the `IntoActivity` is immediately restarting the `HomeActivity` because it thinks it's logged in.

Comment: Prakash answered first so I've given him the tick, what a silly mistake it was. Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you miss commit the shared preference after setting loggedIn as false. So your flag is not updated and your intro activity again redirect you to home activity.

Try

editor.commit();

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, you miss two things to make things work:

1. Add `editor.commit();` just after `editor.putBoolean("logged_in", false);` in order to save your value `"logged_in"`
2. Add `finish();` between `startActivity(introIntent);` and `return true;`

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I've marked Prakash's answer as correct as I saw his solution first and it fixed my problem. However, the extra point in your answer could be beneficial. Am I right in thinking that without using finish() I could potentially stack up a lot of the same activities here?

Comment: Indeed. To be more precise, Android will keep up a reference to the previously launched activities in order to serve them again if the user uses the back button ([good API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) here). Not calling the `finish();` method will put the parent activity to the background. If the device runs on low memory, Android can kill this activity to make room... by calling `finish();`. Killing an activity doesn't affect the references hold by Android for back button trail but it's better in terms of memory consummation.